# google map v2 grey blank page , only zoom is there

Tags: android, dictionary

I am working in Iran, I had used Google map v1 for long time, now that I have to use Google map v2, I just can see a grey blank page with zoom icon only, I have done every thing based on Google instructions,  I think I have done everything. 
***I WANT TO KNOW IF THIS PROBLEM IS RELATED TO GOOGLE POLICY THAT MEANS SOME COUNTRIES ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES AND MAP .... ***
THIS IS A BIG PROBLEM FOR ME NOW
THX

---

```
this is the manifest file of my code :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pea.map001v2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.
permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.pea.map001v2.MainMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCk0HwJYHIjM9W_eqqTB1C5wyB-2B0B5U4" />
</application>

<uses-feature           
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try running the standard Google Maps app. If it works, then probably the issue is not any sort of country-based blocking.

Answer (score 3):

You Must Run your app in amulator having Following Configuration....

1. Google API(x86 System image)
2. Select checkBox indicating  "Use Host GPU..."

Answer (score 1):

If anything this could be related to Iran's policy and not Google's.

The problem you describe usually happens when you have a problem with the API key you have generated or the way you registered it in the Console.

You can go over this blog post I wrote on getting the Google API V2 key:

[Google Map API V2 key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you missed one of this:

- Didn't include the Google API Key v2 in the manifest.xml
- Didn't add the package name in Android maps Key(Console) , example:

> ABczzisierkaiSAisi-Ka2;my.project.package
>
> Didn't add Internet Permissions, on manifest.xml.
>
> Your Android device doesn't have an internet connection
>
> NOTE: If you are using a Virtual Device, it won't work, beacuase it needs Google Play Services

Answer (score 1):

I used to face the same problem as yours. The first thing you need to check is Google Maps Android API Key. Then check the settings in AndroidManifest.xml. There are detail instructions in following link: [Android Maps Android v2](http://thuongnh.com/google-maps-android-v2-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's because of country ._.
 i have this issue too on javaScript apis, but it works out with proxy..